# Animation through C# in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i am trying to make a animation in which all the elements of my particular grid should vibrate.

so i tried this code ..

```
Storyboard hintstoryboard = new Storyboard();

for (int i = 3; i < gridpieces.Children.Count; i++)
{
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleanimation, ((Image)gridpieces.Children[i]).Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleanimation, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)");

    EasingDoubleKeyFrame frame = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    frame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
    frame.Value = -5;

    EasingDoubleKeyFrame frame1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    frame1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
    frame1.Value = 0;

    EasingDoubleKeyFrame frame2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    frame2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
    frame2.Value = 5;

    EasingDoubleKeyFrame frame3 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    frame3.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4);
    frame3.Value = 0;

    doubleanimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame);
    doubleanimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame1);
    doubleanimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame2);
    doubleanimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame3);

    hintstoryboard.Children.Add(doubleanimation);
}

hintstoryboard.Begin();
```

but it is giving an exception that target name is not found but my grid have the image with same same name...  i have made that grid by code only...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Sandeep, can you add a snippet of the XAML that includes the elements you are trying to animate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `SetTargetName` outside of XAML. In code behind you should replace this:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleanimation, ((Image)gridpieces.Children[i]).Name);
```

with this

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleanimation, (Image)gridpieces.Children[i]);
```